# Recognize created Facebook Album on User Return?

Tags: facebook

An album was created and a photo was uploaded for a Facebook user using PHP SDK. When user returns next time and I have to upload another photo to same album. What would be the simplest method to identify the album created already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
you can always get the latest created album with FQL (or latest changed album), the following query should work:

```
SELECT aid, object_id, name 
  FROM album
 WHERE owner=me() 
   AND name='Sample Album'
 ORDER BY modified_major DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

EDIT2:
added AND name='Sample Album' to the WHERE clause (see comments)

Comment: what if the user has created some more albums before his return ?

Comment: The above query gives me recently changed album. I actually want to identify the album created by specific app. In other words, lets say my app created an album named "Sample Album" and uploaded a photo. Before his return to my app, some more albums were create and now my album is at order 3 according to "modify order". 

One way is to query all albums and then compare the names one by one. Is there a simple way identify the  "Sample Album" ?

Comment: What do you mean  by "compare the names". are you storing it's name? in that case you can just store it's id instead.

Comment: using the above query, i pull all the albums and then compare their names to a "Sample Album". If found, it is all right otherwise i create the album. Is there any other way instead of comparing the albums or storing info ?

Comment: if your app sets some reserved name like "Sample Album" you can add it to WHERE clause of the above query: WHERE owner = me() AND name = 'Sample Album'; I edited the answer

Comment: name is not "indexable" as per FQL docs, so it wouldn't work in my opinion

Comment: it works, I tested the query, owner is indexable and that's enough